# Matlab integrate of fitted "linearinterp" returning error "First input argument must be a function handle"

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration, linear-interpolation

Trying to get the integral of some experimentally collected data.

After using the envelope and abs functions I'm using the fit function to get the equation I wish to integrate (unfortunately '`poly`' isn't giving a close enough fit to the data):

```
[yupper,ylower] = envelope(signal,1000,'peak');

dat = abs(yupper);

f = fit(x,dat,'linearinterp');
```

Then when I try

```
q = integral(f,3e4,9e4);
```

I get the error:

> Error using integral (line 82) First input argument must be a function
> handle.
>
> Error in findenergyfromfitcurve (line 10) `q = integral(f,3e4,9e4)`;

I thought `f` was a (mathematical) function, don't understand what the error is telling me. When I try using '`poly3`' incase it's the linearinterp messing things up I still get that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `f` is a function but its type is **cfit** not **function handle**.
- `integral()` function requires **function handle**, what you can do
  is transform **cfit** into **function handle** before taking the
  integral

**The code is as follows**

```
x = rand(5,1);
dat = rand(5,1);
f = fit(x,dat,'linearinterp');

% Create a new function handle
f = @(x)f(x);

q = integral(f, 3e4,9e4,  'ArrayValued', 1)
```

---

> 2) What does the ... 'Array valued', 1) do as well? It didn't work
>   till I put that in so it must do something

`f` is a **piecewise function**, the following illustration is based on the assumption that `f` is a **2-piecewise linear function**, but it can be used for **n-piecewise function** as well.
[image]

The task for `fit()` function is finding the parameters :

- `a`
- `b`
- `c`
- `d`
- `k`

---

**In terms of code `f` looks like**

```
function y = f(x,a,b,c,d,k)
    % PIECEWISELINE   A line made of two pieces
    % that is not continuous.

    y = zeros(size(x));

    % This example includes a for-loop and if statement
    % purely for example purposes.
    for i = 1:length(x)
        if x(i) < k
            y(i) = a.* x(i) + b;
        else
            y(i) = c.* x(i) + d;
        end
    end
end
```

---

**To plot a function handle, just use `fplot(f)`**

Here is the graph for `f`
[image]

---

> To sum up, `f` probably has more than one expression, that's why I set
>   '`ArrayValued`' to **true** so that `integral()` function knowns `f`
>   has more than one expression, omitting it means `f` has a single
>   expression which is not true.

---

Comment: Thanks for this, I have 2 questions though:
1) Why can't I plot f once I've turned it in to a function handle? It works before that line I just don't think I understand function handles properly. 
2) What does the ... 'Array valued', 1) do as well? It didn't work till I put that in so it must do something...